# Is it an idea of OOP?

Tags: scheme, sicp

I have learned data-directed programming from the chapter 2.4 of the SICP, and then I continued to study the chapter 2.5. When I saw the "Tower of types" and "inherit", an thought flashed, is it an idea of OOP? Each package is an object and the "tower of types" shows the relation among the types which has the same meaning like "inherit" in OOP.

I am so excited and hope to know the answer!

Comment: Kinda? Closer to OOP is message passing, IIRC this is also discussed in sicp

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have just read the SICP to chapter 2.5 and do not have a deep understanding of it. But I am so excited to find this, just like find a treasure. So I hope to know more even if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm glad you're excited :) I'd also point you to opencoursewares SICP lectures if you haven't already found them. I found they supplemented the book nicely

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I have heard something about the lecture, but I am a Chinese student, maybe I cannot keep up with the English in the lecture.

Comment: The lectures come with full downloadable transcript and it's not so difficult language. I would have tried the first video. The worst thing would be wasting a little time while the benefits are seeing genious first hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although section 2.5 does introduce the concept of type hierarchies, the "inheritance" mentioned is not as general as OOP's inheritance. In the context of a numeric tower, a type  inherits all *operations* defined on a supertype, that's all.

In fact, in the second edition of SICP OOP is not treated formally - although I think I saw some SICP course notes dealing with OOP once, but they were not part of the book. The closest thing you get to OOP in SICP is the technique of message-passing, but without inheritance.

Check your Scheme interpreter's documentation, it's possible that some full-fledged [object system](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mzlib_class.html) is included within it - but it will have nothing to do with SICP.

Comment: Message passing + delegation does make for "normal" OOP.

Comment: It's ... open to discussion, but without a mechanism for sharing information (be it inheritance, or prototypes) I wouldn't consider it an object system. IMHO the minimum properties needed to qualify as an object system would be inheritance and polymorphism